# Unable to hide form errors by default

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create a simple Angularjs form and is unable to hide the form errors when I first navigate to view. I want the error messages to show only when user clicks Continue button . Here is the component html code:

```
<section class="testApp">
 <form [formGroup]="signUpForm"  (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(signUpForm.value)" >
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2"></div>
            <header class="header col-md-8">
                <h1>Data Entry</h1>
            </header>

        </div>
                    <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <section class="main">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="form-text">*When were you born ?</div>
                            <input class="form-control" id="dob" type="date" [formControl]="signUpForm.controls['dob']">
                            <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="signUpForm.controls['dob'].hasError('required')" >You must enter a date.</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="form-text">Question here  ?</div>
                            <input type="radio" name="res" value="YES" [formControl]="signUpForm.controls['res']" > YES
                            <input type="radio" name="res" value="NO" [formControl]="signUpForm.controls['res']" > NO

                        <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="signUpForm.controls['res'].hasError('required')">You must select an option.</div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="form-text">*Some Important Question here ?</div>
                            <input type="radio" name="ins" value="YES" [formControl]="signUpForm.controls['ins']" > YES
                            <input type="radio" name="ins" value="NO" [formControl]="signUpForm.controls['ins']" > NO
                            <input type="radio" name="ins" value="Unsure" [formControl]="signUpForm.controls['ins']" > I'M NOT SURE
                            <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="signUpForm.controls['ins'].hasError('required') ">You must select an option.</div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <button type="submit"  >CONTINUE</button>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
 </form>
</section>
```

Here is the component.ts file :

```
   export class SignUpComponent {

    signUpForm : FormGroup;



    constructor(private _router: Router, fb: FormBuilder)
    {
      this.signUpForm=fb.group({
        'dob': [null,Validators.compose([Validators.required, AgeValidator.Validate])],
        'res': [null,Validators.required],
        'ins': [null,Validators.required],
      })
    }





}[![By default errors showing up even when the form is not dirty.][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add novalidate to your form:

```
<form [formGroup]="signUpForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(signUpForm.value)" novalidate>
```

UPDATE:

You will defiantly need the `novalidate` if you want reactive validation.

Here is a working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/QdxlDVPi21VJcdnjR9kK?p=preview).

Comment: Thank you but this did not really help me.. On adding the novalidate to form , its still showing all error messages by default. I want error messages to show only when user clicks Continue button and errors still exists on page.

Comment: update helped as i changed my validation condition to :  <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="signUpForm.controls['dob'].hasError('required') && !(signUpForm.controls.dob.valid || (signUpForm.controls.dob.pristine && !submitted))">You must enter a date.</div>